# How to read really LARGE JSON file and insert that file's data into a MYSQL database using node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, large-data

I have large JSON file(22GB). I want to read that file and input that file's data into a MySql database using node.js. How can I do this?

This is my database query:

```
var query = connection.query("INSERT INTO hotels (property_id, name, address,city, state_province_name, postal_code, 
        country_code, star_rate, latitude, longitude, category, rank, collect, property_collect, featured_image, breakfast_included, free_wifi_available) 
VALUES ('" + .... + "', .........;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. Please edit the question to show what you have tried (full code), and mention the error you are getting. Also, please mention the mysql client module are you using, and the version of mysql installed on your system. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: At least I don't have any idea about how to do this. It's a pleasure if anyone can give me a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for this. Thanks, everyone who's tried to help me.

*This is my DB connection(db.js*)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

//connect to db
var dbCon  = mysql.createPool({
   connectionLimit : 50,
   host: 'xxxxx',
   user: 'xxx',
   password: 'xxx',
   database: 'xxxxx',
   waitForConnections: true,
   queueLimit: 0,
 });

 dbCon.on('connection', function (connection) {
    console.log('db pool connection');
    connection.query("SET time_zone='+5:30'");
  });

 dbCon.on('release', function (connection) {
    console.log('Connection %d released', connection.threadId);
 });

 module.exports = {
   dbCon
 };
```

*This is my solution.*

```
var express = require('express');
var app   = express();
var dbCon = require('./config/db').dbCon;
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var stream = require('stream');
var data = '';

// Create a readable stream
var readerStream = fs.createReadStream('./data/myJson.jsonl');

// Set the encoding to be utf8. 
readerStream.setEncoding('UTF8');

var outstream = new stream();
//createInterface - read through the stream line by line and print out data from it
var r1 = readline.createInterface(readerStream, outstream);
var lineCount = 0;

r1.on('line', function (line) {
  // increment line count
  lineCount++;
  data = JSON.parse(line);

saveRecord(data);
})


function saveRecord(data) {

if (typeof data["city "] !== 'undefined') {
    var cityTemp = data["city"];
} else {
    cityTemp = "";
}

var property_id = data["property_id"];
var name = data["name"];
var city = cityTemp;

var sql = "INSERT INTO hotels (property_id, name, city) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

dbCon.query(sql, [property_id, name, city]);

console.log('data inserted');
}

console.log("Program Ended");
```

Comment: If we have 10M records, this code executes 10M insert queries!
as I noticed it reads file line by line. what if json object doesn't fit in one line?

Comment: @AmirRezaM75 In that case, you should consider using jsonl format instead of json

Answer (score 1):

For this big file, streaming is the best way. There is a package called [etl](https://github.com/ZJONSSON/node-etl#mysql) which does that job for you. something like this

```
etl.file('somefile')
  .pipe(etl.mysql.upsert(pool,'testschema','testtable',{concurrency:4 }))
```